# How to execute a JavaScript function with ChartJS and FreeMarker?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, freemarker

I'm trying to execute a JavaScript function in a chartjs pie-graph, but using FreeMarker, and it is a little difficult.

I have the following javaScript function:

```
function randomColor(){
        var hue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
        var color = 'hsla(' + hue + ', 70%, 70%, .8)';
        return color;
}
```

And I want to fill the chartjs attribute "Background":

```
"backgroundColor": [
    <#list object.array as something>
        "${randomColor()}",
    </#list>       
]}]
```

But it does not work...

How can include this function into my chartjs?

I'm using chartjs 2.9.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `"${` and `}"`, so that the function will be called in the browser. FreeMarker statements (like `${...}`) are resolved on the server, which is too early (there's no JavaScript running there).

Comment: When I remove it, I get a list with the function name, but not the value that this function returns. In other words, I get a list of "randomColor()".

Comment: @Victor I assumed that `"backgroundColor": [ ... ]` is JavaScript. In that case you should see `randomColor()`-s (without quotation marks around it) in the source view of the browser, but the actual runtime value should have the random colors.